# Почему звук воспроизводится только после того как нажмешь ОК в алерте? Хочу чтобы звук воспроизводился одновременно с алертом

Tags: javascript

```
function gameOver() {
    soundScream();
    alert(`GAME OVER! Your score: ${score} `);
}
function soundScream() {
    let audio = new Audio(); //
    audio.src = 'sounds/Gameover.mp3';
    audio.autoplay = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте вызвать `alert()` явно после начала воспроизведения звука:

```
function gameOver() {
    let audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = 'sounds/Gameover.mp3';
    audio.autoplay = true;
    audio.onplaying = function() {
        alert(`GAME OVER! Your score: ${score} `);
    };
}
```

[Больше о `playing_event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/playing_event).

Кроме того, задумайтесь над предварительной (это чуть раньше, чем перед самым воспроизведением) загрузкой аудиофайла:

```
<audio src="YOUR/SOURCE.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
```

или

```
audio.setAttribute("preload", "true");
```

Это поможет избежать задержек в воспроизведении, потому что сейчас после появления сообщения (`alert`) часть времени уходит на загрузку данных